# Error on ScrollView+StackLayout when binding minimum_height on Kivy

Tags: python, windows, scrollview, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and I am trying to create a scroll view based the official ScrollView [example](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) on Kivy docs.

I'm using the Kivy portable package for Windows with Python version 3.3.3.

When i try to run the code below with the layout.bind line uncommented i got repeated lines of the following error:

> Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute

When i comment the layout.bind line I get a normal startup with the buttons i added where i would expect them, but the scroll doesn't work.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Example(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = StackLayout(size_hint_y=None)

        # If i uncomment this line, i got the error:
        # layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(30):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(.33,.8))
            layout.add_widget(btn)

        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None,None), size=(400, 400))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

The question is why the scroll doesn't work? and why the layout.bind is causing an error.

How should i do to have the same visual and the scroll working on x axis without the error?

I made this piece of code as close as possible to the Kivy official [example](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're creating an infinite loop. The size of each `Button` is set based on the size of the `StackLayout`. This causes the `StackLayout` to increase in size, causing the `Button` sizes to be recalculated, causing the `StackLayout` to increase in size, ad infinitum.

You're telling Kivy that you want the `Button` size based on the `StackLayout` size, while also wanting the `StackLayout` size based on the combined `Button`s size.

To fix this, you need to specify a real size instead of using `size_hint`:

```
btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and it worked! Make sense now that you have explained.

Comment: @Ryan P, does ignoring this error have any effect with the running of the app or the operating system?, in my case the error iteration stops as soon as the dynamic buttons are loaded.